# What content blocker is this?

Tags: proxy, content-filter

I was using [browsershots.org](http://browsershots.org) to check out what our redesigned Web site looks like in different browsers. One of the distributed VMs giving results (specifically, [vm-fab-964](http://browsershots.org/factories/vm-fab-964/)) apparently lives behind a content-blocking filter, and gave [this error message](http://browsershots.org/screenshots/6315a350c98cd30b76a98879742c8ac6/):

> **Access Denied (content_filter_denied)**
>
> Your request was denied because of its content categorization: "Internet Radio and TV;Bandwidth"
>
> For assistance, contact your network support team.

Our site is not remotely related to Internet radio or TV and our bandwidth usage is trivial, so I need to contact whoever makes this software and arrange to have our site removed from the blacklist. All I have is a screenshot, so I can't view the source to see if the vendor is named in an HTML comment or something. Does anyone recognize this blocking software from the wording of the error message?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Looks exactly like a generic Bluecoat proxy message to me

Bluecoat can use a number of filtering engines including their own, i-FILTER, InterSafe, IWF, Optenet, Proventia, SmartFilter, SurfControl, Websense, and Webwasher.  Administrators can also define websites manually to be in a certain category.

If you google "content_filter_denied", you will see that Bluecoat is mentioned prominently

I tested your domain against our Bluecoat using their integrated filtering and it returned

> Financial Services

I also went to Websense and using their [site lookup tool](https://www.websense.com/sitelookup/Default.aspx), it appears they are categorizing you as

```
Category                Database                Version
Internet Radio and TV   Websense Enterprise     93358
Internet Radio and TV   Websense Web Filter     3362
```

You should use that page to request a re-categorization