# What proxy server gives this authentication error message?

Tags: proxy

I'm trying to do customer support for a web application that we develop and host.  A client just sent me screenshots of "our application" putting up a standard Windows username/password box, then failing to authenticate.  The logs, and everything else I know about our system, indicate that it wasn't actually our application that asked her to authenticate.  The "authentication_failed" message looks like this, in MS IE6: 
[Access Denied (authentication_failed) http://www.pitadeveloper.com/blog/image.axd?picture=2009/8/auth_failed.png](http://www.pitadeveloper.com/blog/image.axd?picture=2009/8/auth_failed.png)

I did some Googling on the issue, and the word seems to be that it's a proxy server that gives this message, but none of the first dozen or so results told me conclusively what proxy server product it was.  My questions are: is it a specific proxy server product and can you tell me what it is?  I need some more specifics before I go back to the client.  Thanks in advance.

Comment: Take a look at the source of that page.  Some proxies will put their name or an indicator in there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on [**this similar question**](https://serverfault.com/questions/50636/what-content-blocker-is-this), I would say it's [**BlueCoat**](http://bluecoat.com/).